# How to pass GitHub's URL to Docker's REST API remote parameter from build function

Tags: rest, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use REST API to build DockerFile from Github repository.

I enabled the docker deamon to listen to TCP 2375.
I verified that it works:
`curl http://localhost:2375/images/json`

I received the list of all my images.

I am trying the `build` command from the Docker API [website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ImageBuild) (or the second [website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#32-images)).

I need to use the `build` command together with the `remote` parameter.

[They](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ImageBuild) wrote:

> A Git repository URI or HTTP/HTTPS context URI. If the URI points to a
>   single text file, the file’s contents are placed into a file called
>   Dockerfile and the image is built from that file. If the URI points to
>   a tarball, the file is downloaded by the daemon and the contents
>   therein used as the context for the build. If the URI points to a
>   tarball and the dockerfile parameter is also specified, there must be
>   a file with the corresponding path inside the tarball.

But I don't understand how to pass the GitHub URL.
I created a simple [repository](https://github.com/stackoverflowquestion/myrepo/blob/master/DockerFile) that contains a DockerFile:
`FROM alpine`

The address of the GitHub repository is:
https://github.com/stackoverflowquestion/myrepo/blob/master/DockerFile

This is what I tried:

```
curl http://localhost:2375/build?remote=https://github.com/stackoverflowquestion/myrepo/blob/master/DockerFile
curl http://localhost:2375/build?remote=https://github.com/stackoverflowquestion/myrepo 
curl http://localhost:2375/build?remote=https://github.com/stackoverflowquestion
curl http://localhost:2375/build?remote=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stackoverflowquestion/myrepo/master/DockerFile
```

None of them work.
I am keep receiving:

```
{"message":"page not found"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the raw version of the link, and specify the method POST:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:2375/build?remote=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stackoverflowquestion/myrepo/master/DockerFile
```